# React Router with mix of Fixed Routers and Dynamic Route

Tags: react-router

I am having routes like

```
/: Login
/A: A Component
/:[dynamic] : B Component
```

Now I am using code Like below, but now every time Component  B is loading, even if i pass "Exact" keyword too.

```
<Route exact path="/">
      <LoginComponent />
</Route>
<Route exact path="/:dynamic" component="Dynamic' />
<Route exact path="/A" component="A" />
```

Answer (score 2):

this happens because the router can not distinguish between the dynamic value or "A" or "".
as I know you can't solve it without make another route for B component, like `"/basicPath/:dynamic"`

Comment: yes but requirement is like that to make it dynamic :(

Comment: but think about path like this: `"/A"` when `"A"` is a `dynamic` value, and this path: `"/A"`. there is no way to distinguish between them